# Why aren't labels appearing in my Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a very simple `ModelForm` in my app that looks like this:

```
# ModelForm
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['created', 'last_modified', 'serial_number']

# Model
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    product = models.TextField(verbose_name='Product Name')
    serial_number = models.TextField(verbose_name='Serial Number')
```

And a form that looks like this:

```
# Form
<form method="POST" action="{% url some_url %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.errors %}
            <div>{{ field.errors }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <div>
                {{ field.label_tag }}:
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="actions">
        <input class="button submit focus" type="submit" value="{% trans "Save" %}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When I check out the view using this, I just see a colon (`:`) followed by the textfield: The label is gone.

[According to the documentation for `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types):

> In addition, each generated form field has attributes set as follows:
>
> - ...
> - The form field’s label is set to the `verbose_name` of the model field, with the first character capitalized.

What mistake have I made?

*I am using Django 1.4.1 if it matters.*

Comment: This looks right. What happens when you do `{{field.label}}` ?

Comment: Nothing; same result.

Comment: What is a `StoreTheme`? Is that another class?

Comment: It is a typo that I've since corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I managed to find that still allowed me to separate each *row* of the form was doing the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url some_url %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.as_ul }}
    <div class="actions">
        <input class="button submit focus" type="submit" value="{% trans "Save" %}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

... the key piece being the `{{ formset.as_ul }}` instead of iterating through each field.

As for why the other listed solution (or the solution in the documentation) didn't work, I will remain baffled.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the field label inside a `<label>` tag. So:

```
<div>
    <label for="id_{{field.html_name}}">{{field.label}}:</label>
    {{ field }}
</div>
```

Comment: That both [contradicts the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-the-formset-in-the-template), and also does not work. I just get a bunch of labels like this: `<label for='id_'>:</label>`

Comment: I had a typo, (now corrected), which works for me. 
You're right: it is a different implementation as the documentation, (although I wouldn't say it _contradicts_ it).

Comment: Even correcting for the typo (e.g. the missing quotation mark), it still does not work for me. More correctly, what you've suggested should not be necessary (as `label_tag` should work).